# SVG rendering in GeoNode: SVG cut in 2

Tags: geoserver, sld, svg, geonode

I try to have an SVG as a symbol in GeoNode but my svg is cut in 2.
Here is my svg :

[image: svg]

and here's my layer style SLD in GeoServer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
     <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld 
    StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Unités vétérinaires</Name>
        <UserStyle>
          <Name>Taux de réalisation</Name>
          <Title>Symboles SVG</Title>
          <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
              <Name>100%</Name>
              <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <PropertyName>STUV15</PropertyName>
                  <Literal>100 (achevé= réception definitive)</Literal>
                </PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </Filter>
              <MaxScaleDenominator>600000</MaxScaleDenominator>
              <PointSymbolizer>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                      <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://hexa-dissemination-public.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/unites_veterinaires/uv_fini.svg"/>
              <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
            </ExternalGraphic>
            <Size>20</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```

And here is the rendering:

[image]

Do you have any idea what is going on? Thanks

Comment: Your SVG is bigger than the 20px you have given it to be drawn in, increase the size

Comment: It enlarges the symbol but does not display it completely

Comment: make it bigger still?

Comment: Can you link to the actual SVG, rather than a picture of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same behavior and I changed the size with Inkscape:

*File> Document properties > Resize page to content > Adjust page to content*

Set unit to px and resize your object to keep width and height under 20px/20px.

[image: inkscape_resize]

SVG display entirely in Geonode after these changes.